# div background images separate when scaling to mobile

Tags: html, background, dreamweaver, fluid

I'm making a website using Dreamweaver CC 2015 and it's fluid grid layout. I got the design as I want it but when I resize the browser to simulate a tablet or smartphone the images do not stay together?

You can see it on this page: www.sverkel.dk

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the value of `background-size`. You are setting it to `100%`, but you should be setting it to `100% 100%`. Once you fix that in the style sheet, the images will always stay together without leaving any gap between them. For example:

```
#midt {
  background-image: url(../billeder/bgmidt.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

**Why does this happen?** If `background-size` only gets one value, it is interpreted as the value of the width of the image, and the value of the height is set to `auto`. You need to specify two values so you are setting both width and height ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)).

---

As explained in the comments below, this may cause some issues with the rounded borders not looking nice as the image is stretched.

If you can, it may be a good idea to move to a CSS-only solution (without images), that will adapt to the screen size and keep the proportions all the time. It will also save you some bandwidth as you'll stop using 100KB in images. The only con is that you may need to do some tricks to make it work in old browsers (although it doesn't seem like you need that, see JSFiddle below).

Something like this (you can also see a more in-depth [sample on this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2290pndg/1/)):

```css
body {
    background: url(http://www.sverkel.dk/billeder/bg.jpg) center center;
}

.gridContainer {
    width:90%;
    max-width:1200px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    margin:auto auto;
    text-align:center;
    background:#e5e5e5;    
}

.gridContainer #top {
    background: #b4b4b4; /* Old browsers */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b4b4b4 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
    height:125px;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.gridContainer #bund {
    background: #b4b4b4; /* Old browsers */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e5e5e5 0%,#b4b4b4 100%); /* W3C */
    height:125px;
    border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

.gridContainer #menu {
    background: #cf5858; /* Old browsers */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cf5858 0%,#902727 100%); /* W3C */
    height:45px;
    line-height:45px;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    border-radius:10px;
    margin:16px;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="top" class="fluid"></div>
  <div id="menu" class="fluid">Forside - Produkter - Priser - Om - Kontakt</div>
  <div id="midt" class="fluid">Hvad så der?</div>
  <div id="bund" class="fluid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works! But... Now the backgrounds look odd when i'm on a smaller screen like my iPhone 6, how can I force it to keep the original aspect?

Comment: That's going to be trickier. Have you consider doing it CSS-without-pictures style? Using gradients, rounded borders, and shadows instead of pictures?

Comment: Wow! That's amazing! is there some way to make the menu go into a dropdown menu as the site gets small?

Comment: Right now i'm working on the menu. For some reason it goes a little to the right?

My html code is: 

<div id="menu" class="fluid">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Forside</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Produkter</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Priser</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Om os</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

CSS code: 

li {
    display:inline;
    padding: 10px 30px;
 font-family:verdana;
 font-size:14px;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 text-align:center;
 text-decoration:none;
 align-content:center;
}

Comment: It goes a little to the right because the `ul` has a default `padding-left`. If you set `ul { padding-left:0; }` then the menu list will be centered again. As per the dropdown option, it's just a matter of having media queries and hiding/showing or modifying styles accordingly

Comment: I got the menu down, but now I want to make my text on the site, only problem is that if I do it with tables the text dont scale when going down to smaller screen, then I try in div but that I cant get to stay under the menu instead of on the left, and if I do the text also don't scale. What can i do?

Comment: having the text on tables or divs shouldn't affect the capacity to scale the text. For the positioning part, I cannot visualize it, maybe it would be better if you create a new question for that.

Comment: I have just made it back to the tables. If you go to www.sverkel.dk and resize the browser window you can see that the test goes outside the design.

Comment: There's no point on using tables for that. It would be better a div with a `width` and `max-width` (the table's width is set to 500 and that's why it overflows when the screen is smaller than that)

Comment: Great, I make it in div and makes a new question for the positioning :)

Comment: Got another q for Alvaro :) I put a logo in the top of the design but when on the smaller screens it gets cut off. What to do? I have tryed many things but can't get it to work?

Comment: Hello again. I have added a logo but can't get it to scale? It just gets cut off? I have tried all the things regarding this in the post but it won't work?

Comment: Remove the `max-width:100% 100%` (it is invalid and ignored), and change the background size to: `background-size:contain` (this will [scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp))

Comment: If this post answered your questions, please check it as the correct one. Thanks.